# Parse nested XML in sencha touch 2

Tags: javascript, html, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

```
<homes>
<home>
<id>XXXXXx</id>
<images>
<image id="1"> .....</image>
<image id="2"> ......</image>
<image id="3"> ...... </image>
<image id="4"> ......</image>
</images>
<floorplans>
<floorplan id="1"> ..... </floorplan>
<floorplan id="2"> ..... </floorplan>
</floorplans>
</home>
<home>
<id>XXXXXx</id>
<images>
<image id="1"> .....</image>
<image id="2"> ......</image>
<image id="3"> ...... </image>
<image id="4"> ......</image>
</images>
<floorplans>
<floorplan id="1"> ..... </floorplan>
<floorplan id="2"> ..... </floorplan>
</floorplans>
</home>
</homes>
```

How to get store  imageurl of corresponding homes from the above XML in sencha touch 2 and show them in carousel when i click corresponding home . currently am showing homes in list view . and i have to append floorplans to same carousel

Comment: let me know.. my answer helped or not

Comment: am working on it only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if xml doc is like this .how to define the model ? we do not have <images>

    <homes>
<home>
<id>home1</id>
<image id="1"> image1</image>
<image id="2"> image2</image>
<image id="3"> image3 </image>
<image id="4"> image4</image>
</home>
</homes>
```

Answer (score 1):

I never tried xml parsing in sencha touch, but i tried today for you.. i got what you want

Parse the complete xml as i posed using model associations

**XML**

```
<homes>
<home>
<id>home1</id>
<images>
<image id="1"> image1</image>
<image id="2"> image2</image>
<image id="3"> image3 </image>
<image id="4"> image4</image>
</images>
<floorplans>
<floorplan id="1"> floorplan1 </floorplan>
<floorplan id="2"> floorplan2 </floorplan>
</floorplans>
</home>
<home>
<id>home2</id>
<images>
    <image id="1"> image1</image>
    <image id="2"> image2</image>
    <image id="3"> image3 </image>
    <image id="4"> image4</image>
</images>
<floorplans>
    <floorplan id="1"> floorplan1 </floorplan>
    <floorplan id="2"> floorplan2 </floorplan>
</floorplans>
</home>
</homes>
```

**Models**

**1. Home**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Home', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',  
    config: {
        fields: [
            {name : 'id',  type: 'string'}
        ],
        associations: [ {
            type: 'hasMany',
            model: 'MyApp.model.Floorplan',
            associationKey: 'floorplans'
        },{
            type: 'hasMany',
            model: 'MyApp.model.Image',
            associationKey: 'images'
        }]
    }
});
```

**2. Image**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Image', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',  
    config: {
        fields: [
            {name : 'id', mapping :'@id'},
            {name: 'image', mapping:  function (node) {
                return (node.firstChild ? node.firstChild.nodeValue : null);
            }}
        ],
        proxy : {
            reader: {type: 'xml', record: 'image'}
        },
            belongsTo: 'MyApp.model.home'
    }
});
```

**3. Floorplan**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Floorplan', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',  
    config: {
        fields: [
            {name : 'id', mapping :'@id'},
            {name : 'floorplan',   mapping:  function (node) {
                return (node.firstChild ? node.firstChild.nodeValue : null);
            }}
        ],
        proxy : {
            reader: {type: 'xml', record: 'floorplan'}
        },
        belongsTo: 'MyApp.model.home'
    }
});
```

**Store**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.home', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    config: {
        model: "MyApp.model.Home",
        storeId : 'home',
        proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url : 'homes.xml',
                reader: {
                    type: 'xml',
                    record: 'home',
                    rootProperty: 'homes'
                }
        },
        autoLoad : true
    }
});
```

**List**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.homesList', {
    extend: 'Ext.List',
    xtype: 'homeList',   
    config: {
        itemTpl: '{id}',
        store: 'home',
        listeners : {
            itemtap: function( me, index, target, record, e, eOpts ){
              // record.images() and record.floorplans() gives respective stores

             // list of images for this record 
                console.log(record.images().getData());

            // list of floorplans for this record
                console.log(record.floorplans().getData());

          // you got what you want, so you can paint carousel using above data
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**List Output**

[image]

**Console output when i click a item in a list**

[image]

Comment: giving me a different url which is not in the current node

Comment: i am getting images of  second set only not the first set

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to define a model and store with an XML proxy, then load the records and create the carousel from them.

Model and store:

```
Ext.define('Images', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            {name: 'image', type: 'string' }
        ]
    }
});

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Images',
    id: 'Test',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'homes.xml',
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            record: 'image',
            rootProperty: 'images'
        }
    }
});
```

Then load the store, and access the image name using `record.raw.childNodes[0].nodeValue` to get the value of the `image` node in the xml.  Assuming that text is the URL of your image, you can then just set the `html` of the carousel items to be a `img` tag with that value as the `src`:

```
store.load(function(records) {
    var items = [],
        i, len = records.length;
    for (i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        items.push({
            html: '<img src="' + records[i].raw.childNodes[0].nodeValue + '" />'
        })
    }

    Ext.create('Ext.Carousel', {
        fullscreen: true,

        defaults: {
            styleHtmlContent: true
        },

        items: items
    });
});
```

Comment: i changed my question  . i need the get respective image and floor plans when i click the home . currently am showing it in listview